# Eclipse WindowBuilder change font size in GUI

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, windowbuilder

Is there a way to change the font size of a label for example, in the WindowBuilder? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: Probably, and knowing window builder, it will ruin your layout...

Comment: Course, you could use label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(24f)) or some such...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]In the properties select show advance options and then under it font.

see in the image i have uploaded in the answer